# How can I communicate two Zoiper Sip clients registered with Asterisk server

Tags: virtualbox, sip, asterisk

How can I communicate two zoiper sip clients registered with Asterisk server, i have MS Windows 7 inthat i have ubuntu in virtualBox, i installed Asterisk server in ubuntu,
i have one Zoiper in windows 7, and another in ubuntu, both are registered with Asterisk server.

but I don't know how to communicate(call from one to another)means what contents to be placed in my zoiper dial box(how can i represent another zoiper address) and also please tell me about the extensions.conf.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you install trixbox or elastic or read this book

http://cdn.oreilly.com/books/9780596510480.pdf

In most cases you have dial to number same as username you put when do registration and have context like

```
[internal] 
exten =>_XXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},,)
```